# Progress bar inside custom dialog fragment - How to pass progress from an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, callback, progress-bar

I have created a custom dialog fragment, inside it I have placed a progress bar. The host activity has an AsyncTask which uploads some images to a server. What I need is a way to pass the progress to the progress dialog fragment, I have tried via variables but it launches the fragmet again and again as the progress changes.

How could I pass the progress values without re launching the dialog fragment while values are changing?

I have tried with an interface as well, but it won't initialise my listener (the listener is always null).

**UPDATE:**
I have solved my problem by launching the dialog fragment in the onStart() method of my asyncTask. Than I have created another method inside the onProgeress() method which passes the progress values forward to the already opened alert dialog:

```
            @Override
            public void onProgress(int position, int length) {
                ((PreloaderDialog) newFragment).passValues(position,
                        length);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                // Show preloader dialog
                newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                        "preloader");
            }
```

And inside my AlertDialog Fragment:

```
public void passValues(int position, int length){
        uploadProgress.setMax(length);
        uploadProgress.setProgress(position);
    }
```

---

### Old code:

my asyncTask (loopj):

private UploadProgressListener progressListener;

```
    public interface UploadProgressListener { 
        public void onProgress(int position, int length);       
    }

    //Interface to send selected image's position for deletion
    public void setUploadProgressListener(UploadProgressListener listener) {  
        this.progressListener = listener;  
    }
```

....

```
    client.post("http://www.edmondvarga.com/laborator/upload.php", params,
                    new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2,
                                Throwable arg3) {
                            System.out.println("Upload failed!" + arg3
                                    + " statys code: " + arg0);
                            if (arg0 == 0) {
                                System.out.println("Retrying Upload!");
                                sendZip();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(int position, int length) {

                            if(progressListener != null){
                            progressListener.onProgress(position, length);
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStart() {

                            // Show preloader dialog
                            DialogFragment newFragment = new PreloaderDialog();
                            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                                    "preloader");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {
                            System.out.println("Success!");
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Multumim pentru Comanda!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                            datasource.deleteAllRows();
                        }
                    });
```

and the progress dialog fragment:

```
public class PreloaderDialog extends DialogFragment implements UploadProgressListener {

    private Builder v;
    private ProgressBar uploadProgress;
    int position;
    int length;

    /*
    public PreloaderDialog() {
        this.position = position;
        this.length = length;
    }
    */

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preloader_dialog, null);

        builder.setView(view);

        OrderActivity progressChanged = new OrderActivity();
        progressChanged.setUploadProgressListener(new UploadProgressListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgress(int position, int length) {
                System.out.println("changed");

            }
        });

        uploadProgress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.uploadProressbar);

        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }


    @Override
    public void onProgress(int position, int length) {
        //uploadProgress.setMax(length);
       // uploadProgress.setProgress(position);
        //System.out.println("progresspos: " + position);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Manually creating activities is a bad idea and this may be the source of your problem.

```
OrderActivity progressChanged = new OrderActivity();
```

You may need to pass the activity as a parameter or cast the `getContext();` also I don't know why you would need an activity there. The target listener should be the dialog and you should set the listener in your activity, not the way arround.

Comment: I have deleted the interface and created two methods, one inside onStart()-this launches the progress dialog, another method inside onProgress()-this passes the values forward to the dialog where I update the progress bar. Hope this makes sense, and will have no problems in the future.